# Convergence of series of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}-\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2}\right) 
x\in[0;1]$$
Could I find the convergence of this series of functions using derivatives?

Comment: It's the natural approach here. The integrals are asking for it!

Comment: Yes, I think that'd be fine here.

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: What, take the derivative?

Comment: Prove it converges at $x=0$ and $x=1$.  Since it is a power series, that is sufficient to show it converges over that interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\in(0,1)$,

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}-G(\sqrt{x})$$ with $$G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+2}$$

$$G'(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$

$$\implies G(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x^2)$$

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})+\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x).$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x).$$

$F(0)=0$

Comment: $F(1)\neq \frac{1}{2}\log 2$. $F(1)=\log 2$. Abel's theorem does not apply since the original series is not a power series but a **rearranged** power series.

Comment: The sum of two power series isn't a power one ?.

Comment: A power series is something of the form $$\sum_{n\geq 0} c_n x^{f(n)}$$ with $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ being an increasing function. Not our case.

Comment: Issues are brought by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks a lot for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in(-1,1)$ we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \text{arctanh}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2} = -\frac{1}{2}\log(1-x) $$
by well-known Taylor series. It follows that, for any $x\in(-1,1)$,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}-\frac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2}\right) = \log\sqrt{1+x}. $$
Equality **does not** hold for $x=1$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\log(2). $$

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$ converges for $x \in [0,1).$ Thus each of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n+1}/(2n+1),$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}/(2n+2)$ converges for $x \in [0,1)$ by the comparison test.  Hence so does your series for these $x.$

For $x = 1,$ your series is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2}\right ) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}.$$

The series on the right can be compared to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$ to show convergence.

Conclusion: Your series converges for all $x\in [0,1].$